# Create post in Tumblr Only using HTTP Requests in python?

Tags: python, http, xmlhttprequest, python-requests, tumblr

I'm trying hard. To publish a post on Tumblr using HTTP Requests only. NO API Wrapper. NO Selenium to simulate the browser actions. (I'm trying to avoid using them)

All went fine, but in the last request (step 8 below) I receive a 404 error response "Not Found". : /

**The process is as follows + or -:**

1. Login to tumblr
2. Get authorization url
3. Authorize the "app" (allow it)
4. Grab the keys (Not really needed for this)
5. Perform a GET to https://www.tumblr.com/dashboard
6. Perform a POST to https://www.tumblr.com/svc/post/get_post_form_builder_data

> Involves Request headers with `'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'` and `'x-tumblr-form-key': form_key`

7. Perform a POST to https://www.tumblr.com/svc/secure_form_key

> Involves Response header with `x-tumblr-puppies` and `x-tumblr-form-key`

8. Perform a POST to https://www.tumblr.com/svc/post/update

> Involves Response headers with `x-tumblr-kittens`

Here's the code:

```
import json
from lxml import html
import requests


class Post:

    def __init__(self):
        # TUMBLR + REQUESTS ATTRIBUTES
        self.username = "my_username"
        self.password = "my_password"

        self.key1 = "RbEuUCkMGmzFFITYeo2YBqW3NAolTwZHK1DINAolTwZHK1DIK1"
        self.key2 = "I3cC5HffUEIA4WjRpQANtmliZV4vixpny4UBNAolTwZHK1DIK1"
        self.key3 = "NUKJjHLmPDRyOKe04J9OzEshGy8IrTAaUEZRNAolTwZHK1DIK1"  # NOT REALLY NEEDED FOR THIS
        self.key4 = "nkRiJv00QIwom9El5rU9lbJM8ecJFwGsmvUANAolTwZHK1DIK1"  # NOT REALLY NEEDED FOR THIS

        self.ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'

        # POST ATTRIBUTES
        self.image_to_post = "http://www.networkforgood.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg"
        self.clickthrough = "http://www.reddit.com"

        # CREATE SESSION, ASSIGN USER-AGENT
        self.session = requests.session()
        self.session.headers = {'User-Agent': self.ua}

        # LOGIN TO TUMBLR
        response = self.session.get('https://www.tumblr.com/login', headers=self.session.headers)
        r = html.fromstring(str(response.text))
        form_key = r.xpath("//meta[@name='tumblr-form-key']/@content")[0]

        payload = {
            'user[email]': self.username,
            'user[password]': self.password,
            'form_key': form_key
        }
        self.session.post('https://www.tumblr.com/login', headers=self.session.headers, data=payload)

        # GET AUTHORIZATION URL
        payload = {
            'consumer_key': self.key1,
            'consumer_secret': self.key2
        }
        console_auth = self.session.post('https://api.tumblr.com/console/auth', headers=self.session.headers, data=payload)

        authorize = self.session.get(console_auth.url, headers=self.session.headers)

        print(authorize.url)

        # AUTHORIZE (ALLOW)
        r = html.fromstring(authorize.text)
        form_key = r.xpath("//input[@name='form_key']")[0].value
        oauth_token = authorize.url.replace("https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=", "")

        payload = {
            'allow': '',
            'form_key': form_key,
            'oauth_token': oauth_token
        }
        console_auth = self.session.post(authorize.url, headers=self.session.headers, data=payload)

        # GRAB KEYS
        r = html.fromstring(console_auth.text)
        keys = r.xpath("//div[@class='l-content clearfix']/script")[0].text[57:-57]
        k = json.loads(keys)

        # PRINT KEYS
        print(k['consumer_key'])
        print(k['consumer_secret'])
        print(k['token'])
        print(k['secret'])

        # OK, FROM HERE AND FORTH I STARTED ASSIGNING THE COOKIES. IN THEORY THIS IS DONE BY DEFAULT BY Requests (SHOULD BE OPTIONAL).

        # GET TO THE DASHBOARD (this could be optional, just to ensure referrer was correct)
        self.session.headers = {
            'User-Agent': self.ua,
            'referer': 'https://www.tumblr.com/login',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': 1,
            }

        cookie = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(self.session.cookies)

        dashboard = self.session.get("https://www.tumblr.com/dashboard", headers=self.session.headers, cookies=cookie)


        # GET to https://www.tumblr.com/new/photo (this could be optional, just to ensure referrer was correct)
        self.session.headers = {
            'User-Agent': self.ua,
            'referer': 'https://www.tumblr.com/dashboard',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': 1,
            }

        cookie = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(self.session.cookies)

        dashboard = self.session.get("https://www.tumblr.com/new/photo", headers=self.session.headers, cookies=cookie)


        # POST to https://www.tumblr.com/svc/post/get_post_form_builder_data
        self.session.headers = {
            'origin': 'https://www.tumblr.com',
            'referer': 'https://www.tumblr.com/new/photo',
            'User-Agent': self.ua,
            'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'x-tumblr-form-key': form_key
        }

        cookie = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(self.session.cookies)

        get_post_form_builder_data = self.session.post("https://www.tumblr.com/svc/post/get_post_form_builder_data", headers=self.session.headers, cookies=cookie)

        # I SAW A GET REQUEST TO THE IMAGE IN (F12 > NETWORK TAB) JUST BEFORE -> POST to https://www.tumblr.com/svc/secure_form_key
        self.session.headers = {
            'User-Agent': self.ua,
            'Accept': 'image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8',
        }

        photo = self.session.get(self.image_to_post, headers=self.session.headers)

        # POST to https://www.tumblr.com/svc/secure_form_key
        self.session.headers = {
            'origin': 'https://www.tumblr.com',
            'referer': 'https://www.tumblr.com/new/photo',
            'User-Agent': self.ua,
            'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'x-tumblr-form-key': form_key
        }

        cookie = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(self.session.cookies)

        svc_secure_form_key = self.session.post("https://www.tumblr.com/svc/secure_form_key", headers=self.session.headers, cookies=cookie)

        # DISPLAY RESPONSE HEADERS, JUST TO CHECK...
        print(svc_secure_form_key.headers)


        # POST to https://www.tumblr.com/svc/post/update
        # WE NEED TO GET x-tumblr-secure-form-key VALUE + ASSIGN IT IN HEADERS AS x-tumblr-puppies        
        x_tumblr_secure_form_key = svc_secure_form_key.headers['x-tumblr-secure-form-key']

        self.session.headers = {
            'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            'accept-language': 'es',
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'dnt': '1',
            'origin': 'https://www.tumblr.com',
            'referer': 'https://www.tumblr.com/new/photo',
            'User-Agent': self.ua,
            'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'x-tumblr-form-key': form_key,
            'x-tumblr-puppies': x_tumblr_secure_form_key,
        }

        payload = {
            'allow_photo_replies': 'false',
            'caption[o1]': "",
            'channel_id': "xxxtrash001",
            'content_stats': {
                'elapsed': '0',
                'embeds': {},
                'gifSearch': {},
                'gifs': {
                    'searches': '0',
                    'added': '0',
                    'kept': '0',
                },
                'htmlLength': 10,
                'images': {},
                'mentions': {},
                'textLength': 3,
                'textTools': {
                    'hr': 0,
                    'h2': 0,
                    'more': 0,
                    'mentions': 0,
                },
            },
            'context_id': "xxxtrash001",
            'context_page': "dashboard",
            'editor_type': "rich",
            'images[o1]': self.image_to_post,
            'is_rich_text[one]': "0",
            'is_rich_text[three]': "0",
            'is_rich_text[two]': "1",
            'loggingData': {},
            'post[date]': "",
            'post[photoset_layout]': "1",
            'post[photoset_order]': "o1",
            'post[publish_on]': "",
            'post[slug]': "",
            'post[source_url]': "",
            'post[state]': "0",
            'post[tags]': "bbb",
            'post[three]': self.clickthrough,
            'post[two]': "<p>aaa</p>",
            'post[type]': "photo",
            'send_to_fbog': 'true',
            'send_to_twitter': 'true',
        }

        cookie = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(self.session.cookies)

        print(cookie)

        # HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
        x_tumblr_kittens = self.session.post("https://www.tumblr.com/svc/post/update", headers=self.session.headers, data=payload, cookies=cookie)

        print(x_tumblr_kittens.headers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Post()
```

I don't know why I'm getting this `404` status code error `Not Found`. Without throwing any traceback/exception... Could you help me ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @Jeflopo? Don't mean to gravedig, but had the same 404 issue and didn't want to create another question.

Comment: Yeah I did it. But I can't remember... I think that the problem was that in the last request the payload must be json and not a python dict... since the request expects json... not sure though